# Polkadot.Js not showing identities of stashes on parachain rpc server

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, pallet-identity

We are running public relaychain rpc endpoints and are further deploying polkadot-parachain endpoints, starting with statemine/statemint/westmint.

Everything works but when using our endpoints in polkadot.js they don't show the identities of stashes but only the stash itself while in other endpoint the stashed translate to identities.

So ours only show "HPUEzi4v3YJmhBfSbcGEFFiNKPAGVnGkfDiUzBNTR7j1CxT" while the other endpoints show "LUCKYFRIDAY.IO". See also [stakeworld rpc](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://ksm-rpc.stakeworld.io/statemine#/collators) versus [parity rpc](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss://statemine-rpc.polkadot.io#/collators)

It could be that this lookup only works when our node get's included in polkadot.js but I doubt thats the problem.

The nodes are running on dedicated updated ubuntu 22.04 servers, latest `polkadot-parachain` running via systemctl, open p2p/ws/wss ports, no errors in the logs. Besides the identity problem everything works perfectly.

What i've tried so far:

- checked that all ports are open
- direct connection vs load balancer
- relaychain connection via rpc `--relay-chain-rpc-urls=` vs running relaychain native via `polkadot-parachain` binary
- relaychain archive node vs pruned node
- downgraded binary (so tried v0.9.420 and v0.9.400)
- Looked at chrome developer tool/console to see if there are specific errors (no difference)

Anybody an idea where to look?

Comment: Very weird. I would consider opening an issue in polkadotjs apps: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues I do not see how this could be a Polkadot/Cumulus issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inclusion of the endpoints in the polkadot.js code the identity lookups started working so apparently identity for parachains is linked with inclusion in polkadot.js.